# Getting value from input box, changing url based on certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

Should be straightforward, but I just can't work out why this will not work! I'm a n00b, first off.

I have two input boxes that users need to fill in, a name and an amount. If these have been filled in, I change the query string on the URL, if not, then I give them a pre-defined query string for the URL.

I can't get a working jsfiddle, as something weird is going on with the & signs for my query string, sigh.

Basically, I cannot get the URL to change on click.

So here's my code, and the non-working jsfiddle for those interested: http://jsfiddle.net/9uk68m6x/

```
        <form>
                <input type="text" class="name">
                <input type="text" class="amount">
            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function() {

                    $('.makeUrl').click(function(){
           var url = 'http://www.website.com',
           nameVal = $("input.name").val(),
                         amountVal = $("input.amount").val();
                         if (nameVal != ''){
                            //if name value isn't blank, then
                                $("a.makeUrl").prop("href", url+'&name='+nameVal+'&free_amount=1&amount='+amountVal+'00');
                            }
                            else (nameVal == ''){
                                $("a.makeUrl").prop("href", "http://www.website.com&free_amount=1&amount=200");
                            }

                    });

                });
            </script>
            <a href="http://www.website.com&free_amount=1&amount=200" class="ctaButton makeUrl">Donate</a>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your script: `else` do not accept any kind of arguments. Use `else if` instead. However, since your condition is binary (`nameVal` is either empty or not), then you can actually make do without the second `if` statement.

Therefore, some changes I have made:

- Revise the conditional statement. You simply have to check if `nameVal` is empty or not using the expresison `!nameVal`.
- Change the `href` attribute using `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`.
- Use `$(this)` in the click function since it is cached

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/9uk68m6x/4/

```
$(function () {
    $('.makeUrl').click(function (e) {
        // Declare variables
        var url = 'http://www.website.com',
            nameVal = $("input.name").val(),
            amountVal = $("input.amount").val();

        // Conditional statement
        if (nameVal) {
            //if name value isn't blank, then
            $(this).attr("href", url + '&name=' + nameVal + '&free_amount=1&amount=' + amountVal + '00');
        } else {
            $(this).attr("href", "http://www.website.com&amp;free_amount=1&amp;amount=200");
        }

        // Check updated href
        console.log($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `?` in there somewhere. A valid parameterized URL would be:

```
"http://www.website.com/?free_amount=1&amount=200"
```

Yeah, that is kinda hard to fiddle when they encode those characters for you before it runs.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple changes to your JS, it seems to be working, at least in JSFiddle.

```
$(function () {
  $('.makeUrl').click(function () {
    var url = 'http://www.website.com',
        nameVal = $("input.name").val(),
        amountVal = $("input.amount").val();
    if( nameVal !== "" ) {
        //if name value isn't blank, then
        $("a.makeUrl").prop("href", url + '?name=' + nameVal + '&free_amount=1&amount=' + amountVal + '00');
    } else {
        $("a.makeUrl").prop("href", "http://www.website.com?free_amount=1&amount=200");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a syntax error at the else. Remove the `(newVal == '')` or use `else if`

Anyway, here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rL52kojj/) what is show you the URL. (Prevent to activate the link, because of `e.preventDefault();`

And it's checkin the `amountVal` also.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="text" class="amount">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.makeUrl').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = 'http://www.website.com',
                        nameVal = $("input.name").val(),
                        amountVal = $("input.amount").val();
                var newUrl;
                if (nameVal !== '' && amountVal != '') {
                    //if name value isn't blank, then
                    newUrl = url + '?name=' + nameVal + '&free_amount=1&amount=' + amountVal + '00';
                    $("a.makeUrl").prop("href", newUrl);

                } else {
                    newUrl = 'http://www.website.com&free_amount=1&amount=200';
                    $("a.makeUrl").prop("href", "http://www.website.com?free_amount=1&amount=200");
                }
                $('#url').html(newUrl);


            });

        });
    </script>
    <a href="http://www.website.com?free_amount=1&amount=200" class="ctaButton makeUrl">Donate</a>
</form>
<div>URL is: <span id="url"></span></div>
```